# Can we say kinetic energy is tangential K.E?

Tags: power, energy

I saw this in my textbook that

$\dfrac{\text{d}K}{\text{d}t} = \dfrac{\text{d}(1/2mv^2)}{\text{d}t}= F_t v$ where $F_t$ is the resultant tangential force on the body.

Now, let $F_t= F\cos\theta$

$$\dfrac{\text{d}K}{\text{d}t} = F\cos\theta v = Fv = \dfrac{F\text{d}r}{\text{d}t} = F\text{d}r$$

So , by writing resultant tangential force . Does it mean that resultant force on the body only or this $F_t$ is a component of resultant force .

If it is resultant force and not a component of it. Then why to write tangential ?

Do we also have radial force then. A resultant must have two components where  $F\sin\theta$ is the radial force or 2nd component. So , we can’t use dot product here but have to use magnitude of  cross product right.. So , will that be right way to solve it ? .

$F \times \text{d}r$ (vector cross product and radial force)?

[image]

Comment: Please try to update the paragraph with proper sentences. Starting from "*So , by resultant tangential force .*", up until the end of that paragraph, a properly constructed sentence hardly exists. Carefully wording your question, shows that you care about the people that are taking time to read and reply to your questions.

Comment: @NMech For sure. You are right.I have edited it now.

Comment: Why is differentiation of Kinetic energy = resultant tangential force ? By saying that , does it mean that Kinetic energy is also a tangential energy? By this I mean is “ whether kinetic energy is a component of resultant energy  or not “?@NMech . Much better edit.

Comment: Yes. @NMech .  . . .

Comment: @NMech I think kinetic energy is itself a tangential component.

Comment: @NMech I am more thankful to you be being patient .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your initial question "Can we say kinetic energy is tangential K.E?": **No**

You have to remember that kinetic energy is a scalar quantity while velocity is a vector quantity. So you can have spatial components for velocity but not for kinetic energy. For a particle, kinetic energy is depended only from velocity's **magnitude** (which happens to be the Euclidean norm of the velocity $\|v\|=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$).

Of course Kinetic energy can have "components" but they have a totally different meaning. E.g. for a rigid body kinetic energy can be either translational $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ or rotational $\frac{1}{2}I \omega^2$.

Now regarding, the equation you are showing, this is most likely from a chapter with respect to Langrange's method for obtaining the equations of motion. In the case you are showing, you are probably describing a planar curvilinear motion. In that case, the resultant force on the body is non zero. The force is also a vector (like velocity). The force can be analysed to components parallel to the velocity and perpendicular.

- the parallel component will change the magnitude of the velocity (see Kinetic Energy)
- the perpendicular component will change the direction (does not affect kinetic energy).

Comment: Yes. Got it . Thanks you